# How to Exclude Project from Being Searched In Visual Studio Ctrl+F?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Just recently I've come across a problem where when I want to update my program to a new version, (Usually I would hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and change all references i.e. 1.0 to 1.1) but now I've added my program's website to the solution, and I don't want the versions there to update.

I want to be able to exclude this project from Find-And-Replace or, even better, exclude all image files and html files.

Whichever is more efficient.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Have you tried changing the file types to what you want to look for in the "Look at these file types" field in the dialog?  That would allow you specify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't notice this until just now

Answer (score 0):

Enter in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type in *.cs under file type field.